# What chapter is the episode 413 of Naruto Shippuden

Tags: naruto

I  want to start reading the manga Naruto Shippuden, but I would rather start reading from the last episode that was aired (currently episode 413). Do you know which chapter that episode (episode 413) would be?

Answer (score 3):

Naruto: Shippuden episode 413, titled *Hopes Entrusted to the Future*, is a filler episode. The entire arc, *In Naruto's Footsteps: The Friends' Paths*, is a filler arc. Meaning, none of the episodes from the arc has a manga equivalent and is anime exclusive.

However, if you want to check the manga equivalent of an episode from the main arc, you can get the episode details from [**Naruto Wikia**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Narutopedia).